# Equivalence of two optimisation problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am confronted with following problem:
Let $\beta\in \Bbb R$ and $y_k\in\Bbb R^n$ for every $k$.

1. minimise $\alpha+\frac{1}{q(1-\beta)}\sum_{k=1}^{q}max(-x^Ty_k-\alpha,0)$

   subject to: $x_j\geq0$ for $j=1,...,n$ with $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=1$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$
2. minimise $\alpha+\frac{1}{q(1-\beta)}\sum_{k=1}^{q}u_k$

   subject to: $x_j\geq0$ for $j=1,...,q$ with $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=1$, $\alpha\in\Bbb R, u_k\geq0$ and $x^Ty_k+\alpha+u_k\geq 0$

This both problem should be equivalent. However I failed to recognise this as in problem (2) the last condition can be rewritten as $u_k\geq-x^Ty_k-\alpha$. Combining with $u_k\geq0$ this would mean that I am allowing $-x^Ty_k-a\leq0$ in the sum, which is 0 in the problem (1).

Comment: What is $a$ in the first formula, did you mean $\alpha$?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, is corrected.

Comment: Note that if the constraint is satisfied in 2., then $u_k \ge \max (-x^Ty_k -\alpha,0)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your hint. I understand it now. So for a fixed pair of $(x,\alpha)$, the optimum value in the second problem becomes to the objective function of the first problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the "epigraph form" of an optimization problem. For any $\alpha > 0$, the problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_x &\quad f(x) + \alpha g(x) \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad  x \in C
\end{aligned}
$$
can be equivalently written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x, u} &\quad f(x) + \alpha u \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad g(x) \leq u \\
  &\quad x \in C
\end{aligned}
$$
The equivalence is quite easy to establish simply by following the definition of the optimum. Thus, any term in the objective function can be "moved to the constraints". Applying this rule to every one of the terms $\max(-x^T y_k - \alpha, 0)$ in problem (1) you wrote, together with the fact that
$$
\max(a, b) \leq c \iff a \leq c \land b \leq c
$$
yields problem (2).